# How to determine where are the differences in the settings for two sites on same server?

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I got VPS with

- NGINX 1.15.2
- PHP-FPM 7.3.5
- Maria DB 10.0.36
- WordPress 5.2

There are two sites with same content and settings (second one is backup with no access from internet). Differences are the access restrictions in nginx config (allow/disallow IPs in server-location section).

**The problem**: sometimes same code generates an error on production site and won't it on backup site. Today it is

```
$_tmp->$key = $this->recursive_unserialize_replace( $value, false, $parent_serialized, $successive_filter );
```

**Help needed**: I'm trying to determine where are real differences in the settings for these two servers to fix that error.

I've compared already settings in:

- WP wp-config.php
- Nginx /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
- PHP /etc/php/7.3/fpm/conf.d

but they are the same except the pools, socks, owners/groups and ssl. Please guide me where are the differences can be?

Comment: `fix that error.` that is not an error that is code.  Can you include what the actual error message says.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix  the error for this situation is 
`FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /var/www/tororo/html/wp-content/plugins/wp-migrate-db/class/Common/Replace.php on line 376" while reading response header from upstream...`
But this is the same plug-in with same php.ini setting on both sites...

Comment: ??  Again you will have to do better then just putting my username.  My telepathy only works within visual range.   This `allow/disallow` can cause issues with resources such as CSS and JS and AJAX as well..

Comment: How much memory does the one machine have, and what is PHP allowed to use.  I assume that your PHP.ini is the same?  Just because PHP is allowed the memory doesn't mean it exists on the machine.   That is about 540 MB.  Which is an odd number to use for a memory limit (multiple of 8's)

Comment: Another tip off is these 2 things `recursive` and `20480 bytes`  failing to include small amounts of memory usually indicates it happened in a loop.  So you may have a recursion error (infinite loop) on one server an not the other, which would suggest the data used is different.  There may be some edge case being triggered in the code for a particular set of data.  No way to know this though, without more context.

Comment: Yes, it looks like you described: it is recursion error (infinite loop) on one server an not the other. But the data, settings and server are the same.